# I want to monitor(notifications)SSM managed instance ping status.Have anyone implemented it?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssm

I want to monitor(notifications)SSM managed instance ping status.It should notify when instance ping status is connection lost.I tried to look for options in cloudwatch event rules but nothing worked.Have anyone implemented it?

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize AWS Config custom rule - something similar to this:

https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/config/home?region=eu-west-1&awsc-custsat-override=promptUser#/rules/configure-rule/add/ec2-managedinstance-platform-check

Above rule relies on inventory to get this detail - which eventually is aggregation of the UpdateInstanceInformation API call by ssm

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-setting-up-messageAPIs.html

As of now, I don't see a ready made config rule that lets you check ping-status - but it should be possible via custom rule which utilizes Systems Manager DescribeInstanceInformation API

You can get some idea about how to work with custom rule, by checking the existing rules: 
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-config-rules
You can also raise a new rule request over there.